# SEHException in VS2010 (and above) but only on .NET4 or higher on Windows 7

Tags: debugging, windows-7, .net-4.0

My company finally upgraded our development team from Windows XP to Windows 7 64-bit computers and I just discovered an odd error with existing code in the new environment.  The project in question references a COM library that's used to interact with our document image management system.  Any attempt to initialize an instance of this API's Library class is now throwing an SEHException.  The error code returned has not been informative.  Here is the full Exception from a stripped-down sample project I wrote to test this problem:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException was caught
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=External component has thrown an exception.
  Source=FileNetTestLib
  StackTrace:
       at FileNetTestLib.Library.Logon() in C:\Projects\Tests\SEHException\FileNetTestLib\Library.vb:line 4
       at SEHException.Form1.btnLogIn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\Tests\SEHException\SEHException\Form1.vb:line 7
  InnerException:
```

While working with my sample project I was able to confirm the following:

- The Exception only occurs when debugging; running without debugging does not throw any exception
- The Exception DOES NOT occur when debugging on Windows XP (tried on two Win7 and two XP computers)
- The Exception DOES NOT occur when we change the target framework to anything lower than .NET 4.  It only occurs on .NET4 or higher.

So to summarize, the error occurs if we are debugging on Windows 7 targeting .NET4 or higher.  It does not occur if we change any one of these factors.

In researching this I discovered that .NET4 changed its security model for how it handles exceptions thrown from non-managed code.  It looked at first like this might relate to the issue, but from what I've managed to learn so far, the changes affect only a subset of SEHExceptions and apparently not the one I am getting because (1) I am able to catch the SEHException in a try...catch block where the change in .NET causes the affected exceptions (corrupted state exceptions) to not be caught by .NET at all unless you make certain changes to your code or config file (which I have not made and have confirmed are not present in my project) and (2) the problem is only occurring for me under Windows 7 and I haven't found anything to indicate that these changes in .NET4 were Win7-specific.

FYI, I don't have a 32-bit version of Win7 so I can't confirm if the issue is specific to Win7 64-bit or Win7 in general.  I AM compiling the project as x86 since I cannot compile it as x64 due to the COM component.  I have also tried this on VS 2013 as well as VS 2010 and get the same results on both.

Since the problem only occurs while debugging I checked which Exceptions I am allowing the debugger to break on (hoping it was selected and I could just uncheck it to get the debugger to ignore it) and SEHExeption is unchecked (under Debug|Exceptions).  I also checked the Debugging options in VS and "Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries" is unchecked.  Changing either of these has not made a difference.

I also tried initializing a completely different COM component (ImageMagick, in this case), to make sure the error wasn't occurring for ANY COM component but I did not encounter any problems with that.  I am about to contact the vendor of the COM component that is causing an issue for me, but I was wondering if anyone else has encountered any similar problem with other COM components and if so if there's a way to prevent or ignore these types of errors when debugging since the error only appears to be generated as a result of running in the debugger.